# ORACLE APEX - Database feedback

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there any mechanism to initialize from the database the execution of some action on the site (e.g. dynamic action)?

I would like that database send to APEX page e.g. "refresh the region". What is the mechanism for this?

I'm using Apex 19.2

Answer (score 1):

APEX apps (and web apps in general) are generally stateless, so they don't have persistent connections to the DB for a particular user/application session. Several APEX objects allow for periodic refresh within a page, or allow you to force a refresh of a region based on something that the user does *on that page, in that session* (i.e. I've clicked a button, now I need to refresh this region). They don't allow you to refresh a region based on what some *other* user in another session has done because there's no visibility or awareness of those other sessions or users. The closest you could come that I can think of would be to have something that would refresh automatically on a set schedule (probably driven by JavaScript) or perhaps that checks an application queue (i.e. Oracle Advanced Queueing) for an event on a set schedule. Perhaps others would have a better idea, but I think your options are limited, and would all have to be driven primarily from the client/browser.

Comment: That's what I thought with the web site... (there is such a possibility in applications). I think I need to check regularly with JAVASCRIPT "flag" if I should refresh, and if I need to refresh it... Anyway, communication with the database is required from time to time, even if there is a reverse communication mechanism.